# Can I write and get a book publish if I'm just 12?

Tags: publishing, novel, young-author

I really want to write a book about the problems I've been having with friendships, but I'm not sure I should write this, because, of course I'm going to change everyone's names, even mine, but the problem is that I'm 12. Teachers always say I'm an amazing writer and I get an A in that subject, but I'm really wanting to write a book, but I'm not sure if I, a kid, is able to publish it, I always have a passion for writing but I'm not sure if kids, such as 12 year olds, can write a book and publish it

Comment: related: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/19194/14704

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, and I am sure that it's been done in the past. If it is something you feel strongly about, you should 100% try  but

However is one think you need to accept from the start: it is *very* unlikely. The publishing world is cutthroat and competitive for adults authors; you could spend your whole life writing and never get published. Publishers get pickier as the author gets younger as they are a bigger liability.

That being said, I return to my original statement: if it is something you feel strongly about, you should try!

Good luck!